# How do I change a matrix entry and return the matrix

Tags: haskell

I want to define a function which takes three parameters, the coordinates i, j and the matrix itself.
It has to change the entry at the given position (i,j) and return the new matrix.

My predefined Matrix:

```
fieldA 1 1 = 0
fieldA 1 2 = 1
fieldA 2 1 = 1
fieldA 2 2 = 0
```

My first attempt was the following code & error:

```
changeValue i j matrix =
        do matrix i j <- 0
        return matrix

test.hs:113:12: error:
    Parse error in pattern: matrix
    Possibly caused by a missing 'do'?
```

My second attemt was the following code & error:

```
changeValue i j matrix =
        map (\a b -> if a == i && b == j then matrix i j <- 0 else matrix i j <- matrix i j) matrix

test.hs:113:58: error:
    parse error on input ‘<-’
    Perhaps this statement should be within a 'do' block?
```

I think the solution is simple but I'm an absolutely beginner in Haskell and
I would appreciate any kind of help

Comment: Why are you using `<-` and `do` blocks? How is `fieldA` a matrix? It looks like a function to me. On second thought, this is a valid way to define a matrix, just not a very intuitive one IMO. Changing a value in the last column of the "matrix" means making a new "matrix" that returns the new value if the input matches the inputs you are changing.

Comment: @Lazersmoke yes, you're right. `fieldA` is a function but should represent a matrix. The idea behind is the game "Battleship". I only tried to use `<-` because `=` doesn't work as well. I got the error message: _Perhaps this statement should be within a 'do' block?_.  Thats the reason why i tried to use a do block.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps you want something like this:

```
changeValue :: Int -> Int -> Matrix -> Matrix
changeValue i j matrix = matrix2
   where
   matrix2 i2 j2 | i2==i && j2==j = 0
                 | otherwise      = matrix i2 j2
```

It is recommended to always add type signatures to your top level bindings. This can greatly help clarifying one's ideas, as well as helping the compiler to provide good error messages.

Comment: Here, `type Matrix = Int -> Int -> Int`. Also, the where clause is redundant, and can be inlined for the same effect.